# User Profile Application - MOSS MA not found

Tags: user-profile-service

I've had an interesting 2 days with a production environment which saw me rebuild a farm in 2007 and upgrade it to 2010. Nearly have everything working bar the fabled UPSA. I seemingly have some kind of proxy server issue in effect. I basically could not execute a crawl on the site unless I specified the proxy server in the sharepoint search configuration. Once I did that the User Profile Service services sprung to life and I thought it was all going to go through but I encountered this issue whereby when I create the connection I get the MOSS MA not found error. I've spent about 3 hours and regularly encounter problems with it but this one might have me beat. I have attached the ULS logs with the error below. unlike others out there with this problem I have the FIM services started, and have done all the habar pre-requsite checks the connection fails almost instantly so its seemingly a connection issue. In my MIISCLIENT I only have the 2 out of the 3 Managed Connections, probably due to the fact it couldn't provision the AD connection. The ULS error log shows a 404 error? Most of the other problems out there show more of a connection denied issue. No firewalls in play here either. I've requested the port be explicitly open on the proxy server since I have no control of it. Failing that I'll be probably calling microsoft.

```
04/17/2012 15:16:33.51  w3wp.exe (0x544C)                           0x44C4  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   d3b3    High        LoadConnections failed trying to fill the connections list. Most likely during RetriveResources because of permissions --- {1}.  Available parameters: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://oakfs-schol1:5725/ResourceManagementService/MEX that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChan... db8619e3-a2d7-475c-bebd-fa7948cde92c
04/17/2012 15:16:33.51* w3wp.exe (0x544C)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same issue and discovered the Forefront Identity Manager Service wasn't started on the server's services.  You may check the Windows Service to ensure it is running.

Comment: wish it was that simple John, there was a permission setting that was missed 'allow log on locally' in gpedit on the machine but the account has been assigned local admin rights. I have not revisited it since end of April.

Answer (score 1):

There have multiple paths of investigation, but bottom line you need to end with - Forefront Identity Manager Service & ForeFront Identity Manager Synchronization Service (check they run), but that to work you need to make sure you follow the exact steps (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049(office.14).aspx) in terms of Accounts used and permissions, do a server reboot before recreating the Service Application and Proxy again.

To get more insight also look at [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150930125433/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sofocle/archive/2011/06/28/user-profile-syncronization-failure-quot-moss-ma-not-found-quot.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a transparent proxy with auto detection recognized by the IE or use an IE configuration which basically is what all Microsoft programs use for proxy settings. Another workaround could be to check for port blocking or service level blocking on a firewall.
There can be literally hundreds of scenarios and ULS logs are not actually helpful because it is not an intra-sharepoint issue.

Comment: Unsure on the reference link?, but thanks for the lead. There could possibly be some service level blocking in effect on the server for sure, I've managed to get the site admins to pull any kind of proxy enforcement from the SharePoint server so I can probably remove that from the equation now.. but its still an issue