# UserProfile Not Running - am I setting myself up for a fall?

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service

I had a question [User Profile Application - MOSS MA not found](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34077/user-profile-application-moss-ma-not-found) still outstanding. I believe its a transparent proxy related problem.

The site does not use My Sites, Social Tagging, or the need to sync ad properties back and forth from SharePoint. I'm just use SharePoint groups for the web part targeting rather than audiences as a workaround for that.

The question is, am I setting myself up for future problems, I know SharePoint maintains its own listing of AD accounts separate from the UPSA so provided that exists do I even need the UPSA to be working or can I just leave it there rotting?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your business requirements. If you don't need any of the benefits that the UPA provides then leave it out. You did not mention a few of the critical elements so don't forget Profiles (the public view) and People Search.

Once configured you can use security to limit access to the Profile, My Site, and Personal Site features. This is what many folks do, though they still implement UPA and People Search.

Comment: I think I was more concerned with if new users were going to end up having an issue with not seeing their display name properly when authenticating against the site, the customer isn't really using the features discussed thankfully. The only thing complained about was My Links after the 2007 to 2010 migration - but thats been deprecated anyway.

Comment: It's possible, but if you are going to eliminate the ability to use the profiles, you could eliminate the name control on the page too.